# How can I express wait(NULL) without getting compilation warning?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

If I compile my program with `cc` then it works. But I must compile using `gcc -pedantic -Wall -ansi -O4`. Then I get a warning for the statement `wait(NULL)`

```
miniShell.c: In function ‘main’:
miniShell.c:84:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘wait’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             wait(NULL);
             ^
```

Can I rewrite it to please the compiler?

Comment: You're missing the `#include` file that declares `wait()`.

Comment: Read the documentation of `wait`, it should tell you what header you need to include.

Comment: @Olaf: Er... But C89/90 is exactly what is generally referred to as "ANSI C". In C mode of GCC compiler `-ansi` switch is equivalent to `-std=c90` switch.

Comment: @Olaf: The ANSI C89 and ISO C90 standards describe exactly the same language. That language is still commonly, but incorrectly, referred to as "ANSI C". But it's been officially superseded by the ISO C99 and C11 standards, each of which ANSI has adopted. Yes, gcc's `-ansi` option refers to the 1989/1990 standard (it's hard to change compiler options without breaking Makefiles), but if you're talking about a version of the language it's best to refer to ISO CNN, where NN is 90, 99, or 11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the *Linux Programmer's Manual*:

```
WAIT(2)                    Linux Programmer's Manual                   WAIT(2)

NAME
       wait, waitpid, waitid - wait for process to change state

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/wait.h>

       pid_t wait(int *status);
```

So add those two `#include`s to use `wait()`.